# Applying IO [a -> b] to single parameter of type a

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I have

```
functions :: IO[a -> b]   -- IO List of functions
param :: IO[a]            -- Single parameter
```

and I want to get

```
result :: IO[b]
result = IO[*first function* <$> param, *second function* <$> param, ...]
```

I somehow could get result of type `IO[IO b]`, but I want `IO[b]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By "single parameter" I assume you mean a one element list. If so, then here's how it's done:

```hs
result :: IO [b]
result = do
    fs <- functions    -- fs :: [a -> b]
    xs <- param        -- xs :: [a]
    let ys = fs <*> xs -- ys :: [b]
    return ys
```

Note that since `xs` is a one element list you're essentially applying every element of `fs` to that value.

This is the same as:

```hs
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)

result :: IO [b]
result = liftA2 (<*>) functions param
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `liftA2 (<*>)` is `(<*>)` for `Compose`, so you can write `result = getCompose $ Compose functions <*> Compose param`. If this pattern is used widely, It might be better to wrap everything in `Compose` (e.g `param : Compose IO [] a` and `result : Compose IO [] b`), then it's simply `result = functions <*> params`.

Answer (score 4):

This looks very much like a simple `<*>`, but we need to call it... deeply. Can we do this using only the `Applicative` instance, without resorting to `Monad`?

Solving a simpler problem first:

```
functions :: IO (a -> b)
param     :: IO a
```

We could use:

```
functions <*> param
```

To get an `IO b`.

Similarly, given a list of functions and a list of values:

```
functions :: [a -> b]
param     :: [a]
```

We could use:

```
functions <*> param
```

To get a `[b]`.

But now to do both at the same time:

```
functions :: IO [a -> b]
param     :: IO [a]
```

This is... trickier, because we'll have to take advantage of the `Applicative` instance for `IO` and the `Applicative` instance for `[]` at the same time. But it's still doable:

```
doubleAp fns x = liftedFns <*> x
  where apList = (<*>) :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
        liftedFns = fmap apList fns :: IO ([a] -> [b])
```

Or the more concise but harder (for me) to parse:

```
doubleAp fns x = ((<*>) <$> fns) <*> x
```

Or, according to [blunt](https://blunt.herokuapp.com):

```
doublAp = (<*>) . ((<*>) <$>)
```

Comment: You could simply do `liftA2 (<*>) functions param`.

Comment: @AaditMShah That's a lot nicer!

Answer (score 3):

`sequence` will get you from `[IO b]` to `IO [b]`, `join` will get you from `IO (IO [b])` to `IO [b]`.